# Find the minimum value of the expression.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, analysis, polynomials

Find the minimum value of the expression. $x,y,z \in R$

$\sqrt{x^2+1}+ \sqrt {4+(y-z)^2} + \sqrt{1+ (z-x)^2} + \sqrt{9+(10-y)^2}$

Comment: Do you have thoughts and can share what you have tried? Where are you having issues? Regards

Comment: Let the points $A: (x,1) \\ B: (z,2) \\ C: (y,4) \\ D: (10,7) \\ E: (0,0) \\ S = d(E, A) + d(A,B) + d(B, C) + d(C,D)= \\ \sqrt{x^2+1}+ \sqrt {4+(y-z)^2} + \sqrt{1+ (z-x)^2} + \sqrt{9+(10-y)^2}$

Comment: That will work perfectly! What is the minimum distance between points $E$ and $D$ ?

Comment: Yes, but I want to know if there is another way to do it.

Comment: another way is LHS$\ge \sqrt{(x+y-z+z-x+10-y)^2+(1+2+1+3)^2}$

Answer (score 3):

$S = d(E, A) + d(A,B) + d(B, C) + d(C,D) \\  \therefore S = \sqrt{10^2+7^2}=\boxed{\sqrt{149}}$